# jQuery AJAX request with node.js not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

So i'm trying to make real-time comments but the comments keep repeating and filling the page with text. How do I stop that from happening.
**My Client-Side Code**
**Show Route**

```
<%- include("../partials/header") %>
<h1><%- video.title %></h1>
<div><%- video.file  %></div>
<p><%- video.description %></p>
<% if(auth){ %>
<% if(auth.username === "Puffier_Fisher"){ %> 
<button class="btn btn-success"><a href="/videos/<%= video._id %>/edit" class="text-white">EDIT</a></button>
<form action="/videos/<%= video._id %>?_method=delete" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE!</button>
</form>
<% } else {} %>
<% } %>
<button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/videos/<%= video._id %>/comments/new" class="text-white">New Comment</a></button><br>
<div id="comments"></div>
<script>
    function findComments() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url: "/videos/<%= video._id %>/comments",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(res){
            res.forEach(comment => {
                $("#comments").append(`<strong>${comment.author}</strong>`, "<br>");
                $("#comments").append(`<p>${comment.text}</p>`);
            });
        }
    });
}
findComments();
setInterval(findComments, 5000);
</script>
<%- include("../partials/footer") %>
```

**My AJAX Route**

```
router.get("/videos/:id/comments", function(req, res){
    Video.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function (err, foundVideo) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            let doc = JSON.stringify(foundVideo.comments);
            res.send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `setInterval(findComments, 5000);` calls `findComments` every 5 seconds - and each time that happens you'll get additional (and the same) output. Do you not want to just call it once, as `findComments()`. (Your `findComments` takes a parameter `i` but it doesn't appear to actually be used in the function.)

Comment: but i wanted the comments to be live

Comment: so the person dosent have to refresh

Comment: @RobinZigmond what do i do

Comment: Oh I see. You're at risk of DOSing your own server that way, but fine. You can clear the contents of `#comments` at the start of the function, or (better) at the start of the Ajax success callback.

Comment: In general if you want to get "live", continuously updating information from your server, you need to look into using Websockets.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank you

Comment: @RobinZigmond could you explain what they are or give me a good article

Comment: Here's a bad way of doing it.  In your loop, check if #comments contains that comment already.   if !$(':contains(comment)')

Comment: @natel ummm thank you i guess

Comment: @natel why is it bad

Comment: As mentioned above, you're at risk of DOSing your server.

Comment: @natel so what is a good way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749470/jquery-chat-with-time